# rsync and delete other dir

Tags: rsync

My script has `--delete --delete-after` for `rsync`. I have a directory with name `releases` in same dir of basedir of `rsync`.
I don't want to delete `releases` directory after each running my script. Which option of `rsync` can help me?
*UPDATE:*
My script of `rsync` :

```
#/bin/dash

fatal() {
  echo "$1"
  exit 1
}

warn() {
  echo "$1"
}

# Find a source mirror near you which supports rsync on
# https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors
# rsync://<iso-country-code>.rsync.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu should always work
RSYNCSOURCE=rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

# Define where you want the mirror-data to be on your mirror
BASEDIR=/home/ubuntu/

if [ ! -d ${BASEDIR} ]; then
  warn "${BASEDIR} does not exist yet, trying to create it..."
  mkdir -p ${BASEDIR} || fatal "Creation of ${BASEDIR} failed."
fi

rsync --recursive --times --links --safe-links --hard-links \
  --stats \
  --exclude "Packages*" --exclude "Sources*" \
  --exclude "Release*" --exclude "InRelease" --exclude "releases" \
  ${RSYNCSOURCE} ${BASEDIR} || fatal "First stage of sync failed."

rsync --recursive --times --links --safe-links --hard-links \
  --stats  --delete --delete-after --exclude "releases" \
  ${RSYNCSOURCE} ${BASEDIR} || fatal "Second stage of sync failed."

date -u > ${BASEDIR}/project/trace/$(hostname -f)

chown 997:997 /home/ubuntu/* -R
```

Comment: I updated my question. Also I replace releases with Mohsen, Mohsen was fake.

Answer (score 0):

The `--delete` options refer only to files that are present on the receiving side but not on the sending side. It is not clear from your question, but it sounds like you have have directory named `Mohsen` on the sending side, which is then synchronized.
If `Mohsen` is the root directory of your synchronization operation you can avoid it by adding a `/`to the source path. I.e. `rsync me@remote/path/there/ local/path/here` will sync the contents of `there` to `here` but not create a directory `there`.
If OTOH `Mohsen` is a subdirectory, you could exclude it (and subtree) by means of the `--exclude`-option.

Comment: I updated my question. Also I replace releases with Mohsen, Mohsen was fake.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should already do exactly what you ask: to ignore `releases` completely and not delete it on the destination.

You could better define the exclusion as `--exclude '/releases/'` to tie it to the top level of the transfer and to define it as a directory, but that's not essential here.